# How to find equation editor in word document using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am writing a macro in VBA Excel, which is used to do some data processing on a word document. During this, I've changed the font name for the entire document to Times New Roman. But I don't want the same change applied to the 'equation editor' boxes in the document, since their font is "Cambria Math". Changing the font to Times New Roman is resulting into ambiguous data.

Comment: Which MS Office version as you using?

Comment: I am using office 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Equations object changed post 2007. Pre 2007, you could work with those objects by declaring `Field` objects. For example

**UNTESTED**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim fldEqn As Field

    For Each fldEqn In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If fldEqn.Type = wdFieldEmbed Then
            If InStr(1, fldEqn, "Equation.3") Then
                With fldEqn.Result.Font
                   '
                   '~~> Rest of the code
                   '
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next oField
End Sub
```

To work with the `Equation Objects` from 2007 onwards you have to use the [OMaths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb257674%28v=office.12%29.aspx) collection.

You can change the font of all the equations using this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim eqns As OMath

    For Each eqns In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        With eqns.Range.Font
            '
            '~~> Rest of the code
            '
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Siddharth... is ther any way by which I can find the block diagrams and change their font type too???

Comment: How are you inserting block diagrams? Insert | Shapes?

Comment: I am actually merging many documents into one, bt while merging, the font, paragraph setting and line spacing is changing. I need to rectify that.
I am trying by using activedocument.shapes method. is there any better way?

Comment: I think you need to ask a separate question for this :) And when you do, explain the exact scenario.